# Unity3d and probably NGUI causing crash on nexus 6 (5.1)

Tags: unity-game-engine, ngui

I am getting following crash just on Nexus 6(5.1 OS) device. I am unable to make out what is causing this kind of crash and how to approach it. Will appreciate any help.

Unity3d version : 4.6.5f1
NGUI version: 2.6.4

Crashlog from device:

```
05-12 11:22:02.401: E/chromium(7468): ### WebView Version 42.0.2311.138 (code 2311138)
05-12 11:22:02.401: E/chromium(7468): --------- beginning of crash
05-12 11:22:02.401: A/libc(7468): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code -6, fault addr 0x1d2c in tid 7489 (main)
05-12 11:22:02.474: I/DEBUG(353): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
05-12 11:22:02.474: I/DEBUG(353): Build fingerprint: 'google/shamu/shamu:5.1/LMY47I/1767468:user/release-keys'
05-12 11:22:02.474: I/DEBUG(353): Revision: '33696'
05-12 11:22:02.474: I/DEBUG(353): ABI: 'arm'
05-12 11:22:02.474: I/DEBUG(353): pid: 7468, tid: 7489, name: main >>> com.xxx.xxxx <<<
05-12 11:22:02.474: I/DEBUG(353): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr 0xc
05-12 11:22:02.506: I/DEBUG(353): r0 858fe2b0 r1 00000052 r2 00000052 r3 00000000
05-12 11:22:02.506: I/DEBUG(353): r4 858fe2b0 r5 00000052 r6 00000052 r7 aad91da0
05-12 11:22:02.506: I/DEBUG(353): r8 af3e9150 r9 af3e9138 sl 00000003 fp aefb5a00
05-12 11:22:02.506: I/DEBUG(353): ip 00000000 sp af3e90c0 lr aac2a577 pc aacbe97c cpsr 200b0030
05-12 11:22:02.507: I/DEBUG(353): backtrace:
05-12 11:22:02.507: I/DEBUG(353): #00 pc 0017797c /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (EsxCmdBuf::GetSpace(unsigned int)+15)
05-12 11:22:02.507: I/DEBUG(353): #01 pc 000e3573 /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (EsxFramebufferObject::LoadStoreCmdBufGetSpace(EsxCmdBufType, unsigned int)+42)
05-12 11:22:02.507: I/DEBUG(353): #02 pc 00174ba5 /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (EsxBltLib::StoreBin(EsxFramebufferObject*, EsxRenderingLayout const*, unsigned int)+108)
05-12 11:22:02.507: I/DEBUG(353): #03 pc 00116881 /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (EsxContext::processAndSubmitRendering(EsxFlushReason)+3936)
05-12 11:22:02.507: I/DEBUG(353): #04 pc 00177435 /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (EsxCmdMgr::Flush(EsxFlushReason)+412)
05-12 11:22:02.508: I/DEBUG(353): #05 pc 0011693d /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (EsxContext::SwapBuffers(EsxRect const*, unsigned int, EglResourceAccessInfo*)+140)
05-12 11:22:02.508: I/DEBUG(353): #06 pc 0011dd43 /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (EglContext::SwapBuffers(EsxRect const*, unsigned int, EglResourceAccessInfo*)+54)
05-12 11:22:02.508: I/DEBUG(353): #07 pc 0011ae89 /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (EglApi::SwapBuffers(void*, void*)+140)
05-12 11:22:02.508: I/DEBUG(353): #08 pc 00005dc5 /system/vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno.so (eglSwapBuffers+28)
05-12 11:22:02.508: I/DEBUG(353): #09 pc 0001237f /system/lib/libEGL.so (eglSwapBuffers+290)
05-12 11:22:02.508: I/DEBUG(353): #10 pc 003cee58 /data/app/com.xxx.xxxx-1/lib/arm/libunity.so
05-12 11:22:02.509: I/DEBUG(353): #11 pc 003d4374 /data/app/com.xxx.xxxx-1/lib/arm/libunity.so
05-12 11:22:02.509: I/DEBUG(353): #12 pc 0039ef74 /data/app/com.xxx.xxxx-1/lib/arm/libunity.so
05-12 11:22:02.509: I/DEBUG(353): #13 pc 001fc76c /data/app/com.xxx.xxxx-1/lib/arm/libunity.so
05-12 11:22:02.509: I/DEBUG(353): #14 pc 002a0124 /data/app/com.xxx.xxxx-1/lib/arm/libunity.so
05-12 11:22:02.509: I/DEBUG(353): #15 pc 003d24e4 /data/app/com.xxx.xxxx-1/lib/arm/libunity.so
05-12 11:22:02.509: I/DEBUG(353): #16 pc 003de1b0 /data/app/com.xxx.xxxx-1/lib/arm/libunity.so
05-12 11:22:02.509: I/DEBUG(353): #17 pc 0067a5af /data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.xxx.xxxx-1@base.apk@classes.dex
05-12 11:22:03.064: I/AudioFlinger(356): BUFFER TIMEOUT: remove(4097) from active list on thread 0xb59c4000
```

Comment: What code changes did you do since the last stable commit?

Comment: Nothing at all, i reverted back to stable commit and still it's happening. As i mentioned, It's happening only on Nexus 6 device with 5.1 update, even on 5.0.1 Nexus 6 is working fine.

Comment: Did you move to a new Unity version recently? Does the crash reproduce every time? Did you test previous commits on this device before?

Comment: I tried on Unity version 4.6.4f and 4.6.5f, results are same. Yes, crash can be reproduce every time. Yes, i tried with all the different commits and the results are same. Since, the crash is happening somewhere in SwapBuffer call. I am unable to filter out what exactly is causing it.

Comment: So, the crash didn't just started happening — you just didn't test on this particular device, correct?

Comment: "crash is happening somewhere in SwapBuffer call" — can you pinpoint the code that causes the crash with a certainty? If so, can you please include it in the question?

Comment: You are correct, i didn't tested it earlier on the device. I only know the condition which is causing the crash, but the exact piece of code is difficult to find as the last log i can get is coming from the end of update cycle. As per my understanding, something is getting set during the code, which is then processed later in the GPU causing this crash. Can we make out anything from the backtrace ? Since, the crash is happening only in Nexus 6 with 5.1 OS. I am not very sure that it's my code which is causing this crash. Highly confused...

Comment: What I would do in that situation is binary search across your whole codebase. Remove half of your code from the project, check if crash still exists — now I know which half of the code it's in (removed one or the one that stayed)! Repeat until I found the single script that's responsible.

Comment: It's pretty big project with multiple plugins and bonded together in order to provide the desired result. It will be near to impossible or more likely highly time consuming which is not in the picture. Though, if we can understand looking at the backtrace that what kind of error could cause this crash then may be we can isolate it. Or, simply what does this backtrace means?

Comment: Yep, I've been through it with a big project: the elimination process took 2 days. But it's still the best thing I can think of, unfortunately. TBH, this bug looks like a Unity bug, but you will have a hard time confirming it anyway.

Comment: Hmmm...I'll see what i can do.Thanks for the response.

Comment: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) - Looks like it's crashing because it's trying to access something that has not yet been initialised. If this is happening only on that particular device, are you sure that your Unity version properly supports ART runtime?

Comment: I am sure Unity 4.6.4f1 supports ART runtime. Though, i suppose most device uses Dalvik.

Answer (score 2):

You got fault addr 0xc, r3 00000000, is not exactly the same as my case.

In my case, it happens when there are no objects rendered on camera, and camera.targetTexture has been set to aRenderTexture, Destroy(aRenderTexture) will crash.

Fix Code 1 (not recommend but works):

```cs
Destroy(aRenderTexture, 1.0f)
```

Fix Code 2 (maybe a better way, attach the follow script on your crashed camera):

```cs
using UnityEngine;

[RequireComponent (typeof (Camera))]
public class CrashFix : MonoBehaviour {
    void Awake () {
        Camera _cam = gameObject.GetComponent<Camera>();
        GameObject _invisibleObj = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Quad);

        _invisibleObj.name = "CrashFix";
        _invisibleObj.layer = GetFirstLayerNumberFromMask(_cam.cullingMask);
        _invisibleObj.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;
        _invisibleObj.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.001f, 0.001f, 0.001f);
        _invisibleObj.transform.position =
            _cam.transform.position + _cam.transform.forward * (_cam.nearClipPlane+_cam.farClipPlane)/2f;

        Material _mat = new Material(Shader.Find("UI/Default"));
        _mat.color = new Color32(0,0,0,0);

        var mr = _invisibleObj.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
        mr.sharedMaterial = _mat;

        Destroy(_invisibleObj.GetComponent<Collider>());
    }

    private int GetFirstLayerNumberFromMask(int mask)
    {
        if (mask == 0) return 0;

        int result = 0;
        while(true){
            if ((mask & 1) == 1) return result;

            mask >>= 1;
            ++result;
        }
    }
}
```